# Google Sheets and ImportXML - Narrowing Results

Tags: google-sheets, xquery, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import my main image from my product page:

When using ImportXML in Google sheets, is there a way to limit the number of results returned from the query?

For example, I am using a formula that returns 3 results:

```
=IMPORTXML($B$1,"//img[@id='product-preview'][1]/@src[1]")
```

The result is:

```
/productmedia/na-media/media-manager-thumbnails/filer_public_thumbnails/app-images/thumbs540/__540x540_car-vent-clip-silo.jpg?v3.16.5-na

/productmedia/na-media/media-manager-thumbnails/filer_public_thumbnails/app-images/thumbs540/__540x540_403720-car-vent-clip-enviro.jpg?v3.16.5-na

/productmedia/na-media/media-manager-thumbnails/filer_public_thumbnails/app-images/thumbs100/__100x100_car-vent-clip-silo.jpg?v3.16.5-na
```

I only need the first result, can this be done inside the initial formula?

I tried specifying the image using its class name, but I keep getting the error "imported content is empty"

Here is the url from which I am importing for reference: https://shopus.norwex.biz/en_US/customer/shop/product-detail/517210?categoryName=all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting 4 results, not 3, but to get only the first one, try

```
=IMPORTXML($B$1,"(//img[@id='product-preview'][1]/@src)[1]")
```